# Syslog-NG version compatibility

Tags: centos6, centos7, syslog-ng

I have 3 servers configured to run syslog-ng.

We'll call the servers `web`, `jump`, and `client`.

`Web` is `CentOS 6`
`Jump` and `Client` are `CentOS 7`

`Jump` is an `OpenVPN server`
`Client` is an `OpenVPN client`
`Web` is on the same private network as `Jump`

Connectivity is working fine between all 3 servers.
I can SSH and ping directly from `Client` to either `Jump` or `Web`, and vice versa.

I have `Syslog-NG` configured on `Client` and `Web` to log to `Jump`, and `Jump` is configured to receive logs from both `Web` and `Client` on `tcp port 514`.

`Client` is able to log to `Jump` without issues.
`Web`, however, does not seem to want to log to `Jump`.

For testing purposes, I disabled the firewall temporarily on `Jump`.

I also stopped syslog-ng on `Web` and ran it in debug mode. There were no errors related to connecting to Jump.

I also am able to telnet from `Web` to `Jump` on `port 514`, so I know there is no routing issue or firewall issues with it, and I know the configuration is good.

Given that the only difference between `Client` and `Web` is the OS version, is Syslog-NG in `CentOS 6` just not compatible with Syslog-NG in `CentOS 7`? I mean has the syslog protocol changed that much that the older version of Syslog-NG won't work with the newer version?

Client: `syslog-ng-3.5.6-3.el7.x86_64`
Jump: `syslog-ng-3.5.6-3.el7.x86_64`
Web: `syslog-ng-3.2.5-4.el6.x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after more investigation that I had 2 issues.

1) When the firewall WAS enabled, I had the internal NIC on `jump` in the wrong zone. Once that was corrected, I was then able to get connected via telnet with the firewall running

2) I compared the config of `client` against `web` again and found that I was missing the `log` line on `web` which indicated to log to `jump` and was present on `client`.

Once the `log` line was added on `web` and the daemon restarted, logging began immediately on `jump`